# Cakephp 2.1 Saving associated objects Manually

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

Mycakephp version is 2.1.1.

i am trying to save the associated model manually using saveAll() function

**Model**

- Employee HasOne Address
- Employee Belongs to Department

so table

> employees(first_name,last_name,age,sex,department_id)
>
> addresses(first_line,second_line,city,state,employee_id)

now employee creation add.ctp has a form which receives input for employee and address

i know

> $this->Employee->saveAll($this->request->data);

this will save the models but
i want to save the association manually

i was going through the official cakephp document [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html)  and i have tried something like this

```
        $this->Employee->saveAll($data, array(
            'fieldList' => array(
            'Employee' => array('first_name','last_name','age','sex','department_id'),
            'Department' => array('first_line', 'second_line','city','state','employee_id')
            )
        ));
```

it is not working , and throws  following errors

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: data
>   [APP\Controller\EmployeesController.php, line 118]
>
> Warning (2): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>   [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 1996]

i am cakephp beginner. please help me.

> $this->request->data: Array

(

```
[Employee] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => Jack
        [last_name] => Robert
        [age] => 32
        [sex] => 0
        [Department] => Development
    )

[Address] => Array
    (
        [first_line] => HSR Layout
        [second_line] => 1st Cross
        [city] => Najem
        [state] => Barel
    )

[Department] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
    )
```

)

Comment: Can you show more from `add()` method? Where you define `$data`?

Comment: can you tell me how to define $data  i have no idea about that

Comment: If you don't define `$data`, you should use `$this->request->data`, so you get the data of your form.

Comment: I have tried that , still did not work

Comment: $this->Employee->saveAll($this->request->data, array(
       'fieldList' => array(
          'Employee' => array('first_name','last_name','age','sex','department_id'),
          'Department' => array('first_line', 'second_line','city','state','employee_id')
       )
   ));

Comment: this shows error:
Warning (2): Illegal offset type in isset or empty [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 3078]

Warning (2): Illegal offset type in isset or empty [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 3078]

Warning (2): Illegal offset type in isset or empty [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 3078]

Warning (2): Illegal offset type in isset or empty [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 3078]

Comment: can you tell me how to define $data and make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research i have found it.

```
       $data = array(
         'Employee' => array(
         'first_name' => $this->request->data['Employee']['first_name'],
         'last_name'=>$this->request->data['Employee']['last_name'],
         'age'=>$this->request->data['Employee']['age'],
         'sex'=>$this->request->data['Employee']['sex'],
         'department_id'=>$this->request->data['Department']['id']
        ),
         'Adress' => array(
         'first_line' => $this->request->data['Adress']['first_line'],
         'second_line'=>$this->request->data['Adress']['second_line'],
         'city'=>$this->request->data['Adress']['city'],
         'state'=>$this->request->data['Adress']['state']
        )

    );


            $this->Employee->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true))
```

this will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using just an array in `fieldList` parameter:

```
$this->Employee->saveAll($this->request->data, array('fieldList' => array('Employee.first_name', 'Employee.last_name', 'Employee.age', 'Employee.sex', 'Department.first_line', 'Department.second_line', 'Department.city', 'Department.state', 'Department.employee_id')));
```

According to manual, `fieldList` expects "an array of fields you want to allow for saving". I think not accepted a multidimensional array.

`$this->request->data` is all fields of your form, you can check with `debug($this->request->data)`.

Comment: does not save employee and depatment

Comment: Did you try without second parameter? Just `$this->Employee->saveAll($this->request->data)`? And checked `$this->request->data` with `debug()`?

Comment: it works fine with $this->Employee->saveAll($this->request->data)

Comment: Ok, you was trying save fields that does not exist in form data. Check database relationship and form fields, I think there is something wrong.